# Vim: toggle comments while keeping indentation?

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin

Current I'm using the `EnhancedCommentify` plugin for toggling comments, in particular those two commands

```
map <M-c> <plug>Comment
map <M-d> <plug>DeComment
```

But the problem is, instead of commenting out lines like

```
____#I am a comment (_ in front is white space)
```

it will show up as

```
#____I am a comment
```

Is there a quick way inside `EnhancedCommentify` to fix this? or other ways to achieve this, best without changing my current key bindings? Thanks.

*BTW* : `NerdTree` doesn't seem to work for my vim version, and I'm not root user, so...

Comment: I know NERD commenter does it this way.

Comment: @Bernhard Yeah, I tried that, but unfortunately the vim7.0 here on my cluster machine doesn't support nerd, not sure why but that seems to be a long-haul fix.

Comment: I use [tComment](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173), which also works that way and claims to work for 7.0.

Comment: @Conner I just checked it up, but it doesn't seem to support pathogen, does it? I use pathogen to take care of all the plugins.

Comment: Pathogen supports almost every plugin, including this one.

Comment: @Conner I cloned the repo into my vim/bundles directory, but it doesn't seem to be loaded by vim. Wired.

Comment: See answer below; let me know if you have any trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out [tComment](https://github.com/VimEz/tComment). I use it and it supports vim 7.0. It allows you to comment across multiple filetypes with the `gc` motion.

> ```
> gc{motion}   :: Toggle comments (for small comments within one line 
>                 the &filetype_inline style will be used, if 
>                 defined)
> gcc          :: Toggle comment for the current line
> gC{motion}   :: Comment region
> gCc          :: Comment the current line
> ```

If you're using pathogen you can install it with

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle; git clone "https://github.com/VimEz/tComment.git"
```

Then just restart vim and you should be ready to go!

Comment: finally get it work, not sure where I did it wrong last time. What's the difference between this gc-movements and <c-_> ones? can I map the toggle command to other keys like Alt-c?

Comment: Some of them overlap, but the ones with `<PARAMETERS>` autofill `:commands ` to make it easier to use the plugin's functionality. For example, let's say I'm I want to comment something with HTML tags even though I'm in a ruby file. I could use `<C-_>a html<Enter>`

Comment: I see. I just did some quick keymapping in my vimrc (I knew essential zero about vimscript), but the purpose here is to remap cc to toggle comments in all normal, insert, and visual modes: 

    `nnoremap cc :TComment<CR>`
,    
    `inoremap cc <ESC>:TComment<CR>i`
,    
    `vnoremap cc :TCommentBlock<CR>`
,    

does it make sense to you, or is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to enable comments in insert mode you can just do `<C-o>cc`. You probably don't want that `inoremap` since words like "success" will trigger the comment function. You can use `:help <leader>` to overcome this.